# Disable interactive movement in UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to disable interactive movement in a UICollectionView in iOS 9.  In reading, I understand that this might be the default state in a UICollectionViewController by using installsStandardGestureForInteractiveMovement, and there are tons of articles out there on how to implement movement.

What we are seeing is the opposite, in iOS 9, movement is allowed by default and we want to disable, not finding a good way to do this in a UICollectionView that is in a UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionView movement is disabled by default when installed separately with a UIViewController.